# Does GeoJSON support lists of FeatureCollection?

Tags: geojson

I have a JSON array of `FeatureCollection` which I want to visualize with tools like http://geojson.tools/ or https://geojson.io/.

```
[
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    ... 
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    ... 
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    ... 
    ]
  }
]
```

But all the tools I tested do not support the visualization of arrays of `FeatureCollection` as this is no valid GeoJSON element. :-(

Does GeoJSON know any element which contains a list of `FeatureCollection`? (Or is there any way to visualize this data?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [GeoJSON Format Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946), arrays of FeatureCollection are not supported.

A FeatureCollection can consist of any number of features of different geometries, so you should be able to combine your multiple FeatureCollections into a single FeatureCollection.